# Ruby on Rails Query a one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two table venues and `events`, a venue can have multiple events, but an event can have only one venue.

The API `get /venues` returns all the venues, with the all events for each venue.
On passing of a param 'happening_today' get `/venues?happening_today=true`,
I need to display all my venues and only those events for each venue that have the `start_date` same as today! If there are no events, a empty array should be displayed.

```
def index

   venues = Venue.all venues = venues.eager_load(:event).where("events.start_time >= ?", Date.today)

   venues = JSON.parse(venues.to_json(:include => [:category, :offer, :event])) 

   render json: {venues: venues}, status: 200

 end
```

Comment: Please could you show what code you have written so far? See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: add some code buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your Venue model:

```
has_many :todays_events, -> { where(start_date: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day) }, class_name: 'Event'
```

and then do this:

```
venues = Venue.includes(:todays_events)

JSON.parse(venues.to_json(include: [:category, :offer, :todays_events]))
```

The minus is that the key for events in JSON will be *todays_events* instead of *events*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Venue has_many :events` and `Event belongs_to :venue`, you can do something like this:

```
Venue.includes(:events).where("events.start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Today.beginning_of_day, Today.end_of_day)
```

Comment: `where(events: { start_date: Today.beginning_of_day..Today.end_of_day })`

Comment: this doesnt serve my purpose, as it then does not display the rest of the venues, I need all the venues displayed and events for each venue that are happening today.